# Gradle tasks loading a JNI library cannot work in daemon mode

Tags: java, gradle, java-native-interface

I have developed a custom Gradle task that needs to load a JNI library (`System.load`), from a custom class loader.
That's not a problem if Gradle is run with `--no-daemon` command line option, but if the task is run in the daemon, the library stays loaded until the daemon feels like garbage collecting my class loader. The consequences are:

- if I run the task again, an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception is thrown since a native library can be loaded by only one class loader.
- on Windows, any removal of the library will fail because it is loaded and locked.

I have tried to execute the loading part of the task in a process-isolated worker so that the library is unloaded when the process ends, but workers also stay around, idle, until a similar work is submitted with the same parameters and the process never ends. I didn't find a way to prevent a worker from being reusable and make it exit after the work.

Any idea how to run a library-loading task in Gradle daemon ?

Comment: Take a look here. Maybe this will solve the issue: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo018

Comment: Thanks for this link. This trick allows to load and unload a dynamic library from JNI code, but the JNI library itself containing this code cannot be unloaded.